# Use Bluetooth to access NXT display

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, software, bluetooth

I'm planning to use NXT to troll my friends, and I want to show something on the screen that I send to it via Bluetooth. To clarify, I want to type it on a computer in another room. Is there a way to do this all in the NXT software? (no coding)
Thanks - Sam.

Comment: Are you using a NXT or EV3? I think I could help you with that problem :)

Comment: The version i use is NXT

Answer (score 1):

You can remotely start and stop programs from the NXT software. So create a simple program that just has a few display blocks and an empty loop at the end to keep the program from stopping then run the program.

Comment: I need it to do this while running a different program.

Comment: Then there will be some coding required. You can send direct commands remotely using a library such as leJOS or MonoBrick. You could use these to draw on the display. However, if there is a program running on the NXT that has Display blocks, it will write over whatever you sent each time it gets to a Display block in the program.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an idea. Have the output of the bluetooth message receiver block run into the input of the display block. Then, I have some other device sending messages that I type in.